# Автообновление приложения при запуске через wix burn

Tags: wix

Я имею приложение, распространяемое с помощью `Wix burn` установщика написанного через `WixSharp Bootstrapper`.

В этом у становщике есть 2 пакета: .msi пакет приложения (внутри приложение WPF) и пакет .net Framework

Мне нужно, чтобы при открытии приложения происходило его автообновление. Раньше я использовал `ClickOnce`  и в нем эта функция была.

Посоветуйте пожалуйста какой-нибудь механизм способный это выполнить.

У меня есть идея вставить в ярлык приложения ссылку на установщик. Установщик будет проверять обновления. Если их нет, то просто открывать имеющееся приложение. Если есть, то будет выводить окно с просьбой обновиться. после обновления автоматически откроет приложение. Мне кажется ClickOnce примерно так и работает, но я еще и недели не работаю с wix и возможно я изобретаю велосипед.